# How do you tell what office someone works out of?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

Do you say she offices out of Lakewood?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for your question. Just so you know, the system has flagged it for review because it's so short. I also see that it's been voted down. While I don't understand why it's been voted down, your questions will generally be better accepted if you provide more detail about why you're asking and what you've already tried to do to find the answer. If you want to improve your question you can always edit it. This might get it some up votes.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the verb "works".

The statement could be phrased as "works in" or "works out of". For someone who typically works on site and rarely, if ever, travels for work, "works in" would be the more common phrasing. "Works out of" would imply that the office is more of a base of operations and that the person often is traveling to other locations as a part of their job.

Comment: 'Works out of' is a mainly North American usage.